# remove edge div padding, but keep size of the images inside this div and depend of this div size

Tags: html, responsive-design

I have four divs arranged in one line. Inside this divs I have responsive and 16:9 images. The padding between divs should be 20px, but edges padding (left for the left image and right for right image) should be 0. Unfortunatelly, then I subtract left margin for left img, and right margin for right img this two images are bigger. I know why, but I have problem with find good way, how to prevent this. [image]

html:

```
<section class="hfeed popular clearfix">
  <div id="article-list-title">
    <h3>Popular posts</h3>
  </div>
  <article class="category-popular">
    <div id='summary-img'>
      <a href=" " title=" ">
        <img src=" " />
      </a>
    </div>
    <!---- text part, not importent here --->
  </article>
  <article class="category-popular">
    <div id='summary-img'>
      <a href=" " title=" ">
        <img src=" " />
      </a>
    </div>
    <!---- text part, not importent here --->
  </article>    
  <article class="category-popular">
    <div id='summary-img'>
      <a href=" " title=" ">
        <img src=" " />
      </a>
   </div>
   <!---- text part, not importent here --->
 </article>                     
 <article class="category-popular">
    <div id='summary-img'>
      <a href=" " title=" ">
        <img src=" " />
      </a>
    </div>
    <!---- text part, not importent here --->
  </article>                    
</section>
```

css:

```
article.category-popular {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

article #summary-img {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    position: relative;
}

article #summary-img a {
    width: 100%;
}

article #summary-img img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

article.category-popular #summary-img img {
    min-height: 200px !important;
}
```

Please, give me some advise or so, how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found answer. I use left/right minus appropriate values for appropriate divs:

```
.popular article.category-popular:nth-child(2){
  left: -10px !important;
 }

.popular article.category-popular:nth-child(3){
  left: -5px;
}

.popular article.category-popular:nth-child(4){
  right: -5px !important;
 }

.popular article.category-popular:last-child{
  right: -10px !important;
 }
```

You can close topic.